# hostname -f hostname: Name or service not known

Tags: php, dns, sendmail, hostname, hosts

I'm pretty burnt on trying to figure this one out. The main problem is that when i use a loop with php mailer to blast email our users, it only gets to some, and I believe this to be a DNS issue.

Here is the mail code

```
function massEmail($from,$subject,$to,$body) {
    require_once('packages/class.phpmailer.php');
    $success = 0;
    foreach($to as $person) {
        usleep(2000);
        $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
        $mail->From = $from;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->FromName = "cmiVFX";
        $mail->Subject = $subject; 
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->AddAddress($person);
        $ret = $mail->Send();
        if($ret) {
            $success++;
        }
    }   
    var_dump($success);
}
```

When running hostname I get this

```
server.cmivfx.com
```

When running hostname -f or --fqdn i get

```
hostname: Name or service not known
```

when restarting sendmail i get

```
hostname: Name or service not known
```

Here is my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1 server.cmivfx.com cmivfx.com
69.162.76.226 server.cmivfx.com cmivfx.com
```

my hostname file is

```
server.cmivfx.com
```

My mail servers point to google apps
so dig cmivfx.com any gives me

```
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11895
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 9, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cmivfx.com.            IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
cmivfx.com.     1553    IN  SOA ns1.limestonenetworks.com. noc.limestonenetworks.com. 1344528611 16384 2048 1048576 2560
cmivfx.com.     1553    IN  NS  ns1.limestonenetworks.com.
cmivfx.com.     1553    IN  NS  ns2.limestonenetworks.com.
cmivfx.com.     1544    IN  MX  1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
cmivfx.com.     1544    IN  MX  5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
cmivfx.com.     1544    IN  MX  10 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.com.
cmivfx.com.     1544    IN  MX  10 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.com.
cmivfx.com.     1544    IN  MX  5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
cmivfx.com.     1519    IN  A   69.162.76.226

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 208.115.254.242#53(208.115.254.242)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug  9 11:48:14 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 268
```

And finally, when i run the mail php code with my gmail its fine. With some others I get

```
Could not instantiate mail function
```

Hopefully I've provided enough information that someone who knows about sendmail can help me out. Thanks so much!

Comment: php's mail() is not reliable, and provides zero in the way of useful diagnostics. Use swiftmailer or phpmailer instead - far better error messages. and check your mail server's log to see what happens to the mails after php hands it over (remember, php doesn't actually deliver the mail, it just drops the envelope into the mail box).

Comment: Hmm, I am using phpmailer, That was the first block of code I provided. Are you seeing somewhere that I'm not?

Comment: Sorry, my bad... too much sugar at work today.

Answer (score 2):

There's conflict between /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname:
change /etc/hostname as:
`cmivfx.com`

If there's special reason you need remain hostname as `server.cmivfx.com`, you may use
`/etc/hostname + /etc/resolv.conf let 'hostname -f'` to get the right FQDN.

You may get some background information here: [configure FQDN on multiple domains supports mail server](http://sowact.com/mutiple-domains-supported-mail-server-with-postfixdevecotmysql-on-ubuntu-12-04-lt1/)